# How to add a string after domain name in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, ecmascript-6

I want to add values from the selected option after the domain name and not change the entire domain name. For ex from the below selected options, I want to add the value after localhost:8000/${value} or domain.com/${value} and keep the text as it is if there's anything.

```
<select id="ThemeSelect" onchange="saveTheme(this.value);">
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="fr">French</option>
  <option value="ru">Russian</option>
</select>
```

So if the domain is domain.com/page and if a user selects French, then the new domain should be domain.com/fr/page and if they select Russian, it should be domain.com/ru/page. The problem is that the domain would be different in most of the cases.

Comment: You can use `window.location.pathname` to get the part of the current URL after the domain name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to redirect to a different path you can use `window.location.pathname = ${value}${path}`. This will redirect you to a differnet path using the same host or domain name.

If you need to redirect to a new host or domain, you can use `window.location.hostname = newDomain` to change the hostname but keep the same path. This would change `domain.com/fr/page` to `new-domain.com/fr/page`.

If you need to change the hostname and path all together, you would use `window.location.href = 'https://newDomain.com/path/to/page'`